# Facebook Messenger API cannot send image with attachment_id

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've followed the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#messaging_types on uploading an image to the facebook graph API.
I've successfully uploaded the img, and got an `attachment_id` as response, as expected.
[image]

---

However, when trying to POST out with that attachment id, I got this error:

`(#100) Incorrect number of files uploaded. Must upload exactly one file."`

Attached is the body and response:
[image]

---

Anybody knows how to fix this? I looked EVERYWEHRE LOL (i think), ranging from facebook developer community posts to other SO posts. One thing to note is both uploading to API using URL image and local image files will give me an `attachment_id`, but still just can't POST out using them.

Thanks.

EDIT: here's the link to the same question on facebook developer community. https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/625390676140313/?post_id=625390679473646

Comment: You did set `is_reusable` to true when uploading the image, yes?

Comment: Try and put the ID into your JSON as a string value, not an integer. Facebook IDs are often beyond the range of a valid integer (depending on the system), and if implicit conversion to a float happens anywhere along the line, they are likely to become invalid.

Comment: @CBroe yup, I passed this when uploading: `{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}`

I also tried passing in as strings, it doesn't work either 